# Reference from other path for child name validation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database like this:

```
"users": {
    "gh483cwonaz8o3mff3": {
        "nick": "mutlu",
        "birthyear": "1996"
    }
}

"nicks" : {
    "mutlu": {
        "uid": "gh483cwonaz8o3mff3"
    }

}
```

The first data will written to database is to "users". Than to "nicks". But "mutlu" in "nicks" should be same with "users>gh483cwonaz8o3mff3>nick" value. 
How can I determine the security rule for a data will written to "nicks".
I tried this but didn't worked:

```
"nicks": {

        ".write": "auth.token.email_verified == true &&  newData.hasChild(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val())"

    }
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you *edit* your question to show the code for the write operation?
 Preferably with hard-coded values for the actual data.

Comment: I didn't code for this. I'm just trying the simulator on Firebase Realtime Database rules page. "Users" previously added on database. I'm trying to write "nicks" part from simulator and I'm getting permission error.

Comment: In that case, please show a screenshot of the problematic write operation in the simulator showing the path you're trying to write, the data you're trying to write to and the authentication you've set in the simulator.

Comment: I've added some screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you're building in your rule doesn't match the structure in the JSON you shared.
I think your security rule for writing to the nicknames should be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "nicks": {
      "$nick": {
        ".write": "auth.token.email_verified == true &&
          root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('nick').val()) == $nick"
```

It's easiest to catch such mistakes by keeping your JSON/path next to the rule: `"users": { "gh483cwonaz8o3mff3": { "nick": "mutlu",`